# jQuery Templates does not render HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

The content of my blog post contains HTML tag in it, and I'm using jQuery Templates (remote loading, following this post - http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/), but they did not format the text with the HTML tags, instead, the tags are displayed as plain text. What do I need to do in order for the HTML to be formatted?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a part that has .text(...) that could be changed to .html(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{html expression}}` to render unencoded HTML in templates.

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html